# How to reduce for loops in C++

Tags: c++, for-loop

[image: Task]

How can I reduce the following program to 2 for loops and 1 print statement:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= iter; i++)
    {
        for (int j= 1; j <= row; j++) 
        {
            printf("*");
            for (int k = 1; k <= col; k++)
            {
                printf("_");
            }
            printf("*\n");
        }
        printf("\n\n\n");
    }
```

Comment: Why only two loops? What's wrong with three loops?

Comment: Why 2 loops? Why not reduce to one or zero?

Comment: My teacher asked for only 3 instructions so that's how she requested we write it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can merge any count of loops, using multiplication and rest from division (just the multiplication has not to overflow).

```
void f(int iter, int row, int col) {
  for (int i = 0; i < iter * row * col; i++) {
    printf("%s%s%s%s", 
           i % col == 0 ? "*" : "",
           "_",
           i % col == col - 1 ? "*\n" : "",
           i % (row * col) == (row * col) - 1 ? "\n\n\n" : "");
  }
}
```

Comment: hey I've been thinking about this for over an hour. I hate to bother you but can you please explain it briefly so I can understand why and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) to concatenate all things to print to reduce print statements.
- You can use the constructor `basic_string( size_type count, CharT ch, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );` to eliminate the innermost `for` loop.

```
std::string ret = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= iter; i++)
    {
        for (int j= 1; j <= row; j++) 
        {
            ret += "*";
            ret += std::string(col, '_');
            ret += "*\n";
        }
        ret += "\n\n\n";
    }

printf("%s", ret.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

With the range-v3 library, you don't need any loops at all.

```
namespace rv = ranges::views;

auto line = "*" + std::string(col, '_') + "*\n";

auto block = rv::repeat_n(line, row) | rv::join;

auto result = rv::repeat_n(block, iter) | rv::join("\n\n\n");

std::cout << (result | ranges::to<std::string>);
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/oqfK1M).